# How to get a construction paper look in photoshop or illustrator

Tags: texture

I am looking to create some graphics or logos that look and feel very much like that thicker colored construction paper in photoshop or illustrator cs6

Example here:  http://dribbble.com/shots/908746-EOY-2012-Hot-Springs?list=users
and here : http://dribbble.com/shots/133424-Marina?list=users

Any thoughts here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of the texture you're looking for?

Comment: Te easiest solution is to merely find a texture and overlay it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Illustrator:

- Fill a shape with the desired color.
- Create a second fill via the Appearance Panel. Make the second fill black. Highlight this fill in the Appearance Panel.
- Choose Effect > Texture > Grain. The settings below are a good starting point. Lower the intensity if you want more grain.

[image: Grain]

- Now set this black fill to Multiply for the Blend mode and reduce the opacity so the grain is less prominent.

[image: grain]

You can repeat the fills with various grain settings to enhance the texture if you'd like.

[image: more grain]

Photoshop:

- new layer above contents
- Fill new layer with black
- Filter > Noise > Add Noise and adjust settings so there's small amount of white noise.
- Image > Adjustments > Invert
- set Noise layer blending mode to Multiply and reduce the opacity to your liking.
- If you want this on a shape, then Option/Alt-click between the two layers.
- You can further enhance the grain by repeating the above steps and scaling the noise layer up to create larger "clumps" of noise. There's an answer to <kbd>**[this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/how-do-i-get-this-uneven-airbrush-effect-similar-to-old-art-deco-posters/9486#9486)**</kbd> which will provide some detail on adding grain to images in Photoshop.

[image: Photshop]

Answer (score 2):

**Those are raster texture images placed in Illustrator. Probably scans of actual paper.** Scott's answer will do in a pinch but that's not what's going on in the samples you provided. They're a little more convincing than Illustrator's effect.

[SubtlePatterns.com](http://subtlepatterns.com/?s=paper&submit=Search) has some very nice paper textures to choose from. You could also try your hand and building your own tileable texture.

I've done a screen shot version of how to quickly [create a tiled patten](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/15535/4216) before. Here's the quick run down.

1. Place the texture of your choosing
2. Use a transform effect to move and duplicate the linked/embedded file horizontally with as many duplicates as needed.
3. Apply another transform to cover the vertical dimension
4. Apply a clipping mask to restrict the texture to your desired area
5. You can apply a background color to the clipping mask and blend the placed text into it

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial will help you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXaMpsZIk9Y

It goes into detail about how to create a distressed texture. It uses a halftone effect, but you don't have to do that.